# How to get out of a timeout due to an endless loop on python

Tags: python

whenever I run my program all it does is run the menu shown below, however for the part in which the user should choose their option this message shows: "Your Program may have a endless loop"   , what can I Do to terminate the loop and activate the menu so that the user can enter in their option

```
from operator import itemgetter
    high_scores = {"Benson ":100, "fizzlepop":300,"Mikey123":200}

def main():
    choice = None
    while choice != "0":

        print(
        """
        Hi scores system
        0 - Quit
        1 - Look up someone's high score
        2 - Add a score
        3 - Update a score
        4 - Display all high-scores
        """
    )
        #After this point, the program begins to go into a time out as it seems to be going into an endless loop 
        choice = input("Choice: ")
        #exit
        if choice == "0":
            print("Goodbye")

        #look up a score
        elif choice == "1":
            player = input("Whose score would you like to look at?")
            if player in high_scores:
                score = high_scores[player]
                print("\n", player, "'s score is ", score)
            else:
                print("Sorry, player ", player, "not in system")
        elif choice == "2":
            #Your answer to question 2 here-> this is where the user should be able to add a new name and score to the program
            name= input("\nEnter new player name: ")
            score= input("\nEnter score: ")
            high_scores[name] = score
            print("\n",name, "has been added")

        #edit a high score
        elif choice == "3":
            #Your answer to question 3 here
            print("Complete this part of the program")

        #display all high scores
        elif choice == "4":
            for key, value in sorted(high_scores.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse = True):
                print(key, value)

    if __name__ == "__main__":
         main()


    PythonDictionaryScoreProgramIncomplete.py
```

Comment: Are you on Python 2, by any chance?

Comment: Try a `print` with `repr(choice)` after the input to see what it contains.

Comment: What OS? What Python version? How are you running your program?  (I do not recognize that message as coming from Python itself.)

Comment: Note: in Python3 `input()` returns a string; in older versions of Python `input()` evaluates input and returns a type which depends on how the interpreter treats the input as a source code literal expression (which might be a string, an integer, or some other type --- or it might raise an exception if the input is not parseable).

Answer (score 0):

As other users have suggested, try changing:

```
choice = input("Choice: ")
```

To:

```
choice = str(input("Choice: "))
choice = str(input("Choice: ")).lstrip().strip() # Might be better in case you get an input like "0 " or " 0" etc
```

And see if that fixes it.